# AngularJS: angular-drag-and-drop-lists nested demo not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I am working with [angular-drag-and-drop-lists](https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists). I am trying to replicate [this](http://marceljuenemann.github.io/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/demo/#/nested) locally.

I run the code from a local WAMP server. When I click on any 'Item' or 'Container', it is not getting the 'selected' class assigned. In fact the click event is not at all being captured by angular-drag-and-drop-lists library.
So none of the drag and drop functionality is working.

Am I missing something?

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<head>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
        <ul dnd-list="list">
            <li ng-repeat="item in list"
                dnd-draggable="item"
                dnd-moved="list.splice($index, 1)"
                dnd-effect-allowed="move"
                dnd-selected="models.selected = item"
                ng-class="{'selected': models.selected === item}" 
                ng-include="item.type + '.html'" > 
                {{item.label}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="container.html">
        <div class="container-element box box-blue">
            <h3>Container {{item.id}}</h3>
            <div class="column" ng-repeat="list in item.columns" ng-include="'list.html'"></div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </script> 

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="item.html">
        <div class="item">Item {{item.id}}</div>
    </script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="demo" ng-controller="NestedListsDemoController as demoController">
        <div class="col-md-10 ng-scope">
            <div class="row">
                <div ng-repeat="(zone, list) in models.dropzones" class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="dropzone box box-yellow">
                        <!-- The dropzone also uses the list template -->
                        <h3 class="ng-binding">Dropzone {{zone}}</h3>
                        <div ng-include="'list.html'" class="ng-scope"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div view-source="nested"></div>

            <h2>Generated Model</h2>
            <pre>{{modelAsJson}}</pre>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Here is the JS:

```
angular.module("demo", ['dndLists']).controller("NestedListsDemoController", 
function($scope) {

$scope.models = {
    selected: null,
    templates: [
        {type: "item", id: 2},
        {type: "container", id: 1, columns: [[], []]}
    ],
    dropzones: {
        "A":[
                {
                    "type": "container",
                    "id": 1,
                    "columns": [
                        [
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "1"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "2"
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "3"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "4"
                },
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "5"
                },
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "6"
                }
            ],
        "B":[
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": 7
                },
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "8"
                },
                {
                    "type": "container",
                    "id": "2",
                    "columns": [
                        [
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "9"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "10"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "11"
                            }
                        ],
                        [
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "12"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "container",
                                "id": "3",
                                "columns": [
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "item",
                                            "id": "13"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "type": "item",
                                            "id": "14"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "15"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "item",
                                "id": "16"
                            }
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": 16
                }
            ]
    }
};

$scope.$watch('models.dropzones', function(model) {
    //console.log ("Model: " + modelAsJson);
    $scope.modelAsJson = angular.toJson(model, true);
}, true);

});
```

Here is the css:

```
.dropzone ul[dnd-list] {
    margin: 0px;
    min-height: 42px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    }
.dropzone li {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    padding: 0px;
}
.dropzone .dndDragging {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
  .dropzone .dndDraggingSource {
    display: none;
}
  .dropzone .dndPlaceholder {
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: block;
    min-height: 42px;
}
.dropzone .selected .item {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
}

  .dropzone .selected .box {
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
  .dropzone .selected .box > h3 {
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#dff0d8 0,#d0e9c6 100%);
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    color: #3c763d;
}
  .dropzone .item {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

  .dropzone .container-element {
    margin: 10px;
}
  .dropzone .container-element .column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: any error logs in console?

Comment: No. When I do an inspect element of the code in that demo and the local code, the only difference I see is the click event handlers are handled by angular.js in the demo whereas it is being handled by bootstrap.js in the local code.